# Django: fields missing in the Queryset

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

I have this simple e-commerce project where I am trying to render ItemDetailView using slug, but object_list from Product views.py doesn't have them in the Queryset. I inspected the Queryset and I see many fields missing including Vendor.name
Queryset:

<QuerySet [{'id': 11, 'category_id': 1, 'vendor_id': None, 'title': 'sample - user1', 'slug': '', 'description': 'sample pic', 'price': Decimal('3.00'), 'date_added': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 18, 2, 54, 48, 714506, tzinfo=), 'image': 'uploads/IMG-20191217-WA0021_qII27R4.jpg', 'thumbnail': 'uploads/uploads/IMG-20191217-WA0021_qII27R4.jpg'}]>

Please help with this. Thanks in Advance

```
#apps/vendor/models.py
class Vendor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    created_by = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name = 'vendor', on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

#apps/vendor/views.py
class RegisterMember(CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('core/frontpage')
    template_name = 'vendor/register_member.html'

class LoginView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Vendor
    template_name = 'vendor/registration/login.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('vendor/member_admin.html')

class MemberAdminView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Vendor
    template_name = 'vendor/member_admin.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MemberAdminView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['products'] = Product.objects.all()
        return context

class AddItemView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = ProductForm
    template_name = 'vendor/add_item.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('vendor/member_admin.html')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super(AddItemView, self).form_valid(form)

#apps/product/models.py

class Category(models.Model):
    cat_title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 255)
    ordering = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['ordering']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cat_title

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name = 'products', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, related_name = 'products', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 255)
    description = models.TextField(blank = True, null = True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 6, decimal_places = 2, blank = True, null = True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'uploads/', blank = True, null = True, default = None)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'uploads/', blank = True, null = True, default = None)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_added']

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
        
    def get_thumbnail(self):
            if self.thumbnail:
                return self.thumbnail.url
            else:
                if self.image:
                    self.thumbnail = self.make_thumbnail(self.image)
                    self.save()

                    return self.thumbnail.url
                else:
                    return 'https://via.placeholder.com/240x180.jpg'

    def make_thumbnail(self, image, size = (300, 200)):
        img = Image.open(image)
        img.convert('RGB')
        img.thumbnail(size)

        thumb_io = BytesIO()
        img.save(thumb_io, 'JPEG', quality = 85)

        thumbnail = File(thumb_io, name = image.name)

        return thumbnail
#apps/product/views.py

class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'items/item_detail.html'

    print('From Product Views...')
    #print(request.user)
    print([p.slug for p in Product.objects.all()])
    print([p.category for p in Product.objects.all()])

    def get_queryset(self):

        return get_list_or_404(Product, category__slug = category_slug, slug = product_slug)

#template/frontpage.html
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Welcome | {% endblock %}

 {% block content %}
   <div class="columns is-multiline mb-6">
      <div class="column is-12 has-text-centered mt-6 mb-6">
         <h2 class="is-size-3">Latest Items</h2>
         <h2 class="is-size-3">{{ object_list.values }}</h2>
      </div>
      {% for item in object_list %}
         <div class="column is-3 product-list-item">
            <div class="box">
               <figure class="image is-4by3 mb-4">
                  <img src="{{ item.get_thumbnail }}">
               </figure>

               <h2  class="subtitle">{{ item.title }}</h2>
               <h3 class="price is-size-6 mb-5">${{ item.price }}</h2>
               
               <hr>
               <a href="{% url 'items/item_detail.html' item.category.slug item.slug %}" class="button is-dark is-capitalize">View</a>

               
            </div>
         </div>
      {% endfor %}
   </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: this is the error I get when I try to access detailview of the product django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'items/item_detail.html' with arguments '('hardwares', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<category_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P<product_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

Comment: you won't get `vendor.name` because vendor is another Model - so your queryset will give you only the `vendor.id`